# How to run bash script from android activity

Tags: android, bash, android-activity

I'm new android app developer
I want to know how to run a bash script from my android activity

I did this that I found here

```
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds) {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
    for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
       os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
    }           
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
    os.flush();
}
```

but now I got a lot of errors like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N4KC.png]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to surround them with a **try/catch** block, it's a Java rule, try this code instead:

```
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds) {
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
    for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
       try {
        os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }           
    try {
         os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    try {
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second, manually execute su, then the command id to see if can become a root, just in case.